# How does React determine if a reference type state is new?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that when a state is of primitive type, React performs a shallow comparison between the old state and the new when `setState()` is called, and will not rerender if the two are identical. When the state is reference type, however, React doesn't perform a deep comparison between new and old. Based on this test [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ntosds?file=index.js), when I `setState()` with a newly constructed (though identical to a human eye) object, it rerenders the component. This is expected. However, when you return `count` (the original object returned by `useState()`) or `prev` with a functional `setState()`, React somehow knows that it is the same state and decides not to re-render. I am curious as to how it is able to determine that, despite `count`/`prev` being identical to `{ value:0 }` when a deep comparison is performed?

Here's a rough version of the code inside the component (check the above snippet for demo):

```
console.log('Component re-rendered') // Will log if 'willRerender' is true
const [count,setCount] = useState({ value: 0 })

const handleUpdate = willRerender => {
  console.log('setState is called')
  if (willRerender) {
    setCount(count) // The same effect is achieved with setCount(prev => prev)
  } else {
    setCount({ value: 0 })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because both of them have the same reference, `count == count`, but, `count != {value: 0}`, this is expected comparison behaviour of javascript.

Comment: Yes I think this is obvious.